# Analytic continuation for special case of Appell's $F_2$ hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, analytic-continuation

I am looking for an analytic continuation of the function $f(z)$ when $1/2<z<1$. Here is the function in a few different forms.
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z)%
&=(1-z)^2F_2(\alpha;1,1;\alpha,\alpha;z,z)\\
&=(1-z)F_1(1;\alpha-1,1;\alpha;z,z(1-z)^{-1})\\
&={_2F_1}(1,1;\alpha,z^2(1-z)^{-2}),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\alpha>2$ is an arbitrary positive real parameter, $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the first and second Appell hypergeometric functions and $_2F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function.

All of these forms are defined by absolutely convergent series when $z\in (0,1/2)$.  I know $f(z)$ is real and strictly increasing for $z\in(0,1)$.

Resources detailing the analytic continuation for the Appell function in this special case would also be acceptable.

**Additional Information:**

The function $f(z)$ is defined by the limit $f(z):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)$ where
$$
f_n(z)=\left(\frac{1-z}{1-z^{n+1}}\right)^2\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}(1)_k(1)_\ell}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell k! \ell !}z^{k+\ell}.
$$
Here is a plot for various $n$ and $\alpha=10$ along with the limiting solution using $_2F_1$ form (black).

[image]

Another definition for $f_n(z)$ is
$$
\tag{1}
f_n(z):=\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(zx)^k}{(\alpha)_k}\right)^2 x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx}{\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(zx)^k}{(\alpha)_k} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\right)^2}.
$$
The first definition I provided above comes from evaluating and simplifying this one.

**Here are three ways to get $f(z)$**:

> **(1):**

Noting that $f(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)$ we have from $(1)$ that
$$
f(z)=\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \left({_1F_1}(1;\alpha;zx)\right)^2 x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx}{\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty {_1F_1}(1;\alpha;zx) x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\right)^2}.
$$
The numerator and denominator are directly evaluated with formulas $7.622.1$ and $7.621.5$ from Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (ed. 8), respectively. For the numerator, the corresponding formula requires $\alpha>0\land z<1/2$ while the formula for the denominator requires $\alpha>0\land z<1$. Evaluating yields
$$
f(z)=\frac{(1-z)^{-2}{_2F_1}(1,1;\alpha;z^2(1-z)^{-2})}{\left((1-z)^{-1}\right)^2}={_2F_1}(1,1;\alpha;z^2(1-z)^{-2}).
$$

> **(2):**

Evaluating $(1)$ directly we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_n(z)%
&=\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(zx)^{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx}{\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(zx)^k}{(\alpha)_k} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{%
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{z^{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell}%
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha+k+\ell-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx%
}{%
\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{(\alpha)_k}%
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha+k-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\right)^2%
}\\
&=\frac{%
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{z^{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell}%
\Gamma(\alpha+k+\ell)%
}{%
\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{(\alpha)_k}%
\Gamma(\alpha+k)\right)^2%
}\\
&=\frac{%
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell}z^{k+\ell}%
}{%
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n z^k\right)^2%
}
\end{aligned}
$$
Simplifying yields
$$
\tag{2}
f_n(z)=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell}z^{k+\ell}.
$$
Now write $(2)$ as
$$
f_n(z)=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}(1)_k(1)_\ell}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell k! \ell !}z^{k+\ell}.
$$
Evaluating the limit $n\to\infty$ we find (assuming $z\in(0,1)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z)%
&=(1-z)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}(1)_k(1)_\ell}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell k! \ell !}z^{k+\ell}\\
&=(1-z)^2F_2(\alpha;1,1;\alpha,\alpha;z,z),
\end{aligned}
$$
where the double series converges if $|z|+|z|<1\implies 2z<1\implies z<1/2$. Using the reduction formulas of [DLMF 16.16.3 and 16.16.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.16) we then find
$$
f(z)={_2F_1}(1,1;\alpha;z^2(1-z)^{-2}).
$$

> **(3):**

Recalling equation $(2)$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_n(z)%
&=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell}z^{k+\ell}\\
&=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+k+\ell)}{\Gamma(\alpha+k)\Gamma(\alpha+\ell)}z^{k+\ell}\\
&=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha-(-k)-(-\ell))}{\Gamma(\alpha-(-k))\Gamma(\alpha-(-\ell))}z^{k+\ell}
\end{aligned}
$$
According to [Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0002.01) if $\alpha>-(k+\ell)\implies \alpha>0$ (which it is), then
$$
f_n(z)=\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{n+1}-1}\right)^2
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n{_2F_1}(-k,-\ell;\alpha;1)z^{k+\ell}.
$$
Evaluating the limit yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z)%
&=(1-z)^2
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty{_2F_1}(-k,-\ell;\alpha;1)z^\ell\\
&=(1-z)^2
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_\ell}{\ell!}{_2F_1}(-\ell,-k;\alpha;1)\left(1-\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)\right)^{-\ell}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
According to [DLMF $15.15.1$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.15.E1), the series over $\ell$ converges for $z<1$ yielding
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z)%
&=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty{_2F_1}(-k,1;\alpha;z(z-1)^{-1})z^k\\
&=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_k}{k!}{_2F_1}(-k,1;\alpha;z(z-1)^{-1})\left(1-\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^2\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^{-1}\right)^{-k}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Again calling on [DLMF $15.15.1$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.15.E1), the series over $k$ converges for $z<1/2$ yielding
$$
f(z)={_2F_1}(1,1;\alpha;z^2(1-z)^{-2}).
$$

**Remarks**

In all three examples we required $\alpha>0$ and $z<1/2$.  However, if we also impose $\alpha>2$ then using [Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0002.01)
$$
f(1/2)=\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha-2},\quad \alpha>2
$$
which is finite. If we further impose $\alpha>3$ and again call on [Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0002.01) then
$$
\lim_{z\to 1/2^-} f^\prime(z)=8\frac{\alpha-1}{(\alpha-2)(\alpha-3)},\quad \alpha>3
$$
which again is finite.  Also keep in mind that $f_n(z)$ is real, continuous, differentiable, and strictly increasing in $z$ for $z\in(0,1)$ and $n=1,2,3\dots$. Given these results it seems unlikely that $f(z)$ cannot be continued for $z>1/2$. Maybe my intuition is misguiding me here. I am open to being convinced otherwise.

Comment: Since your function reduces to Gauss hypergeometric function, why even bother with Appell? There's a lot of info on the analytic continuation for the Gauss hypergeometric function. The best way would be using the Euler integral, I think. In case the integral doesn't work (for some $\alpha$) then you'll need to consider the differential equation

Comment: @YuriyS I think part of the problem is that the analytic continuation of ${_2F_1}(s)$ has branch points at $s=1$ and $s=\infty$ and I am not sure how to handle that.  Note that in my case, $s=z^2/(1-z)^2$ for $z\in(1/2,1)$ which implies $s\in(1,\infty)$.  I am pretty sure Mathematica has the analytic continuation for ${_2F_1}$ built-in.  When I evaluate $f(z)$ in Mathematica for $z\in(1/2,1)$ it returns a complex answer which I know cannot be correct.

Comment: It does return a complex number in that case, as it's supposed to do for arguments $>1$. If your original function is real, then maybe the reduction formula can't be applied for some reason? I'm not sure. I'll look into this if I can

Comment: @YuriyS Yes.  I think there may be a problem using the reduction formula here which is why I included the other forms.  I attached some plots and additional information to my question that might be useful.  Thank you.

Comment: How do you know that "$f(z)$ is real and strictly increasing for $z\in(0,1)$"? I can't tell from the series definition, but mainly because I forgot how to find the radius of convergence for double series.

Comment: @YuriyS I have a (rather extensive) proof showing $f_n(z)$ is strictly increasing on $z\in(0,1)$ for any $n=1,2,\dots$. Also, $f_n(z)$ is the ratio of the variance over expected value squared of a real and positive random variable so it must be real and positive.

Comment: Ok, @ AaronHendrickson I checked numerically, and your double series only converges for $z<1/2$ and possibly for $z=1/2$. Now I understand your problem. It would help if you elaborate a little on the main definition for the function (from your last comment) since unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with probability theory

Comment: @YuriyS The series does converge for $z=1/2$ and is equal to $f(1/2)=1+1/(\alpha-2)$ see http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0002.01 . Also, $f(z)=\mathsf{E}W^2/(\mathsf{E}W)^2$ where $W$ is a real and positive random variable.  I could elaborate more if you like but my point was that $f(z)$ must be real and positive.  You can also see that $f_n(z)$ is real for $z>1/2$ for various $n$ in my post.

Comment: @YuriyS In case it helps, I added another definition for $f(z)$ to clarify further.

Comment: It helps. The integral in the numerator doesn't converge for $z>1/2$ because the confluent hypergeometric function behaves like the exponential. This is the root of all your problems. You can't claim $f(z)$ exists for $z>1/2$ using this definition either

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you for your thoughts. Given that $f(z)$ is finite at $z=1/2$ and has a finite derivative at $z=1/2$ (I can show this using $_2F_1$ form) are you suggesting that it could still be nonfinite for $z>1/2$? This seems strange to me.

Comment: I'm not sure. Yes, it seems pretty weird to me that it exists for $z=1/2$. It shouldn't... I give up, sorry, maybe tommorrow I'll have some thoughts. In any case, look up the asymptotics for ${_1F_1}$

Comment: @YuriyS Fair enough.  Thank you for taking the time to check it out.  If anything comes to mind I am all ears.

Comment: $\sum_{k \geq 1} x^k/k^3$ has a left derivative at $x = 1$ but is indeterminate for $x > 1$. I think you should instead plot $f_n(z)$ for a fixed $z > 1/2$ (and add $k! \, l!$ in the denominator in the screenshot), it should be clear that the sequence diverges.

Comment: @Maxim, $k! l!$ are not needed in the denominator, because $k! =(1)_k$, the OP just used those factors to get the Appell function form

Comment: @YuriyS I added three ways to derive $f(z)$ plus some remarks at the end of my post.  I don't know if they are helpful but I put them there just in case.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson, the properties of $f_n$ don't directly translate into the properties of $f$.  Every definition for $f(z)$ itself that you have only works for $z<1/2$, maybe for $z=1/2$ as well. But not for $z>1/2$. When we come to the ratio definition, then in the numerator for $z>1/2$ we are integrating an exponentially increasing function. Clearly, the integral doesn't converge in the usual sense.

Comment: You could assign some value to it, or to the divergent series, but I'm not sure if the result would make any sense in your particular application. In whatever context you need $f(z)$, you need to make sure $z>1/2$ even makes sense in that context

Comment: @YuriyS You are right.  I used the properties of $f_n$ to infer properties of $f$ which in this case got me into trouble.  $f$ is indeed finite at $z=1/2$ and you can have as many one sided derivatives as you like at $z=1/2$ for sufficiently large $\alpha$.  That said, I am now convinced that in the limit, the continuous function $f_n$ becomes discontinuous at $z=1/2$, that is, $f(1/2)$ is finite but $f(1/2+\epsilon)=\infty$. Very strange.

Comment: @YuriyS Oh yeah. In fact, there's no need to resort to numerical tests, if this double series converges, it converges absolutely and, for $\alpha = 3, \, z = 3/4$, is equal to
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} \left( \sum_{l \geq 0} \right) =
8 \sum_{k \geq 0}
 \frac {3^{k - 2} (16 - 4^{-k} (3 k + 7)} {(k + 1) (k + 2)} =
\infty.$$
$x = 1$ is a branch point of ${_2 F_1}(a, b; c; x)$, we need to specify which branch we choose for an analytic continuation from $0 < x < 1$ to define its value for $x > 1$.

Comment: @Maxim Is there a way to specify a branch cut such that the analytic continuation of $f(z)$ is real for $z\in(1/2,1)$?

Comment: Consider ${_2 F_1}(1, 1; 3; x) = 2 (x + (1 - x) \ln(1 - x))/x^2$, where $0 < x < 1$ and $\operatorname{Im} \ln(1 - x) = 0$. If $x > 1$, then $\operatorname{Im} \ln(1 - x) = (2 k + 1) \pi$ for any analytic continuation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but some information in attempt to clear the air.

Using the first definition for the limit function, we have:

$$f(z)=(1-z)^2F_2(\alpha;1,1;\alpha,\alpha;z,z)$$

Using the [integral definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) for this Appell function we obtain:

$$f(z)=(1-z)^2(\alpha-1)^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)^{\alpha-2}(1-v)^{\alpha-2} du dv}{(1-z (u+v))^\alpha}$$

Just as the series only converges for $z \leq \frac{1}{2}$ (if we are looking for $z>0$ at least), it's clear that the integral only exists for $z \leq \frac{1}{2}$, because otherwise it blows up for $\alpha >1$. And we can't have $\alpha <1$ either, because of the terms in the numerator.

We can define the function for $z>1/2$ as the Cauchy principal value of the integral, but that's all I can offer.

The fact that $$f_n(z)=\left(\frac{1-z}{1-z^{n+1}}\right)^2\sum_{k,\ell=0}^n\frac{(\alpha)_{k+\ell}(1)_k(1)_\ell}{(\alpha)_k(\alpha)_\ell k! \ell !}z^{k+\ell}$$

all exist and are real for $z>1/2$ doesn't mean anything, because what we are looking for is the limit $f(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(z)$.

My claim is as follows. For $z>1/2$ neither the "limit of the partial sums definition" nor the "double integral definition" would work as stated.

---

Some further thoughts. The integrand is symmetric, so we can redefine:

$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(1-z)^2(\alpha-1)^2}= 2\int_0^1 \int_0^u \frac{(1-u)^{\alpha-2}(1-v)^{\alpha-2} dv du}{(1-z (u+v))^\alpha}$$

$$v=u t$$

$$g(z)=2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)^{\alpha-2}(1-t u)^{\alpha-2} u dt du}{(1-z (1+t) u)^\alpha}$$

$$g(z)=2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(1-(1+t)u+t u^2)^{\alpha-2} u dt du}{(1-z (1+t) u)^\alpha}$$

Not sure if this could help us, but just in case.

---

Update:

Using the other definition:

$$f(z)=\frac{\int_0^\infty \left({_1F_1}(1,\alpha,z x)\right)^2 x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx}{\left(\int_0^\infty {_1F_1}(1,\alpha,z x) x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\right)^2}+1$$

It's clear that the integral in the numerator doesn't converge for $z>1/2$, because the confluent hypergeometric function behaves like the exponential.

Meanwhile, the integral in the denominator does converge for $1/2<z<1$.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to provide the analytic continuation using any of those definitions.